# Python: Type Hint for "has method"

Tags: python, types, annotations, type-hinting, python-typing

For example, we have a class:

```
class A:
    def send(msg: bytes) -> None:
        # implementation...
        pass
    
    def recv(n: int) -> bytes:
        # implementation
        pass
```

and a function:

```
def a(obj, n: int) -> None:
    received = obj.recv(n)
    obj.send(received)
```

It's fairly obvious, that not only instances of class `A` can be passed as the `obj` argument, but also instances of `socket.socket`, maybe other classes, which have `recv` and `send` implemented.

How can one annotate/type hint `obj` argument, so that it says something like:

```
obj type must possess methods send and recv
send method must be of type Callable[[bytes], None]
recv method must be of type Callable[[int], bytes]
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you exactly need is [duck-typing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing) (structural subtyping) via [typing.Protocol](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Protocol). Some examples are in this [list](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#protocols).

> Protocol classes are defined like this:
>
> ```
> class Proto(Protocol):
>     def meth(self) -> int:
>         ...
> ```
>
> Such classes are primarily used with static type checkers that recognize structural subtyping (static duck-typing), for example:
>
> ```py
> class C:
>     def meth(self) -> int:
>         return 0
>
> def func(x: Proto) -> int:
>     return x.meth()
>
> func(C())  # Passes static type check
> ```

Where a builtin example is

> **`class typing.SupportsIndex`**
>
> An ABC with one abstract method `__index__`.

So for your case, it could be something like:

```
from typing import Protocol


class SupportsSendReceive(Protocol):
    def send(self, msg: bytes) -> None:
        ...
    
    def recv(self, n: int) -> bytes:
        ...


def a(obj: SupportsSendReceive, n: int) -> None:
    received = obj.recv(n)
    obj.send(received)
```

- Note that the [ellipsis](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#the-ellipsis-object) `...` doesn't mean you have to substitute code into it. It is really how it should be. Or you could also put `pass` in there if the 3 dots are bothering :)